# Java config beans from dependent Spring project are not being initialized

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a 3 Spring projects: 'web', worker' and 'core'.

'core' includes common functionality from 'web' and 'worker' such as domain beans or jpa repositories and it is included in 'worker' and 'web' projects as jar.

### POM in 'web' project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.proyecti.magmainside221b</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RC1</version>            
</dependency>
```

When I deploy 'web' project in Tomcat looks like Java config beans from 'core' are not being initialized since the '***datasource***' bean (defined in 'core' project with @Bean in one class annotated with @Configuration) is not found to be injected into ***'PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices'***.

```
Caused by: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#1978517' of type [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1978517': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dataSource' is defined
```

What I have to do to initialize my java config beans from 'core' project when I deploy 'web' project?

Thanks!

### Edited:

I have found in the logs that my applicationContext files are being loaded.

```
2014-09-22 15:04:37,922 INFO [unknown] [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.b.f.x.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from file [/home/aacevedo/workspaces/magma/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/web/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]
2014-09-22 15:04:37,940 INFO [unknown] [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.b.f.x.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/home/aacevedo/workspaces/magma/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/web/WEB-INF/lib/core-1.0.0.RC1.jar!/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-core.xml]
```

I n my 'core' project I (think that) don't need applicationContext  since I am using Java config and my main configuration class looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSpringConfigured
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.proyecti.magma.common.datasources.internal.repositories")
@ComponentScan( basePackages = {"com.proyecti.magma"}, 
            excludeFilters=
            {
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.ANNOTATION, value=Controller.class)
            })
@Order(1)
public class BasicDataSourceConfig 
{
...
}
```

I have put a breakpoint into BasicDataSourceConfig constructor but it is not being reached.

When I had unified this projects everithing worked ok.

Update 2:

This is how my project structure looks like:

### [image]

Comment: Can you show the Spring configuration of both the `web` and `core` modules?

Comment: Edited with more info :)

Comment: What does the component scan look like in the web project? What package is `BasicDataSourceConfig` in?

Comment: If have added a screenshot with the info but the `BasicDataSourceConfig` constructor is not being reached in debug mode

Comment: Can you post 'web' context configuration?

Comment: Can you please post the Java config that you are using in the web project? Thanks

Comment: I am using several java config...one for each topic (websockets, tiles, security, i18n, etc.) but any of the breakpoint put in each constructors of each Java config classes are being reachable in debug. I have even tried to put the java config I have show you in update 2 inside my 'web' project with order 1 but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I am asking because I want to see what kind of component scanning you have enabled in your web project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have found a configuration that works for me.

It seems that ***@ComponentScan*** was not being detected when it was included in a config way with the annotation...I have created a regular applicationContext.xml file in my 'web' project adding the component-scan object with XML and now my @Configuration classes in both projects are being detected successfully.

Answer (score 2):

You need to import 'core' context into 'web' context using `@Import` annotation.

Comment: @tstorms This may be solution for him

Comment: @tstorms I updated my answer. It's not question now.

Comment: As i have told to @geoand, I am using java config so xml file should not be needed (i didn't need it when I had the project unified).